# Delete End Node to a relationship with neo4j cypher query

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Spring neo4j and Java.  I have `@NodeEntity` on the classes I wish to persist.  In some of these classes, I have data members annotated with `@RelatedTo` and `@Fetch`.  I want to be able to delete one of my classes containing `@NodeEntity` and delete all data memembers connected to it vi its `@RelatedTo` and `@Fetch` annotations.  I have created a delete query in attempt to delete the node and its nodes connected to it via their relations:

```
   @Query("start n = node:uid(uid={0}) "
        + "match n-[*]-x WITH x MATCH x-[r]-() "
        + "delete x,r")
public void deleteByUid(String uid);
```

This deletes the top level node and its relations, but leaves behind the nodes that were connected via the relationship to the top level node.  How can I modify the query to do this with cypher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try

```
@Query("start n = node:uid(uid={0}) "
    + "match n-[*0..]-x WITH x MATCH x-[r]-() "
    + "delete x,r")
public void deleteByUid(String uid);
```

Since `*` is defaulting to `[*1..]`.

Comment: Cyper Query Language is too powerful!